# Pandas - export group by 3 columns to JSON

Tags: python, pandas

I have `carsML` dataframe about cars:

```
+-------+-------------+--------------------+
| Manuf |    Model    |        Type        |
+-------+-------------+--------------------+
| VW    | VWModel 1   | VWModel 1 Type 1   |
| VW    | VWModel 2   | VWModel 2 Type 1   |
| VW    | VWModel 2   | VWModel 2 Type 2   |
| Opel  | OpelModel 1 | OpelModel 1 Type 1 |
| Opel  | OpelModel 2 | OpelModel 2 Type 1 |
| Opel  | OpelModel 2 | OpelModel 2 Type 2 |
+-------+-------------+--------------------+
```

I need to export unique values to JSON. I know how to get 2 levels:

```
j = carsML.groupby('Manuf ')['Model'].unique().to_json()
```

which is giving me nice JSON for `Manufacturers` and `Models` but I don't know how to extend that on 3rd level (`Types`).

Final JSON should look like this:

```
{"Opel":
{"OpelModel 1": ["OpelModel 1 Type 1"]},
["OpelModel 2":["OpelModel 2 Type 1","OpelModel 2 Type 1"]],
"VW":
{"VWModel 1":["VWModel 1 Type 1"]},
{"VWModel 2":["VWModel 2 Type 1","VWModel 2 Type 2"]}}
```

Comment: How should looks final json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `MultiIndex Series` by grouping by 2 columns and then create in dictionary comprehension nested dictionaries:

```
s = carsML.groupby(['Manuf','Model'])['Type'].unique().apply(list)
d = {l: s.xs(l).to_dict() for l in s.index.levels[0]}
```

For `json` use `json.dumps` from nested dictionaries:

```
import json
j = json.dumps({l: s.xs(l).to_dict() for l in s.index.levels[0]})
```

---

```
print (j)
{"Opel": {"OpelModel 1": ["OpelModel 1 Type 1"], 
          "OpelModel 2": ["OpelModel 2 Type 1", "OpelModel 2 Type 2"]},
 "VW": {"VWModel 1": ["VWModel 1 Type 1"], 
        "VWModel 2": ["VWModel 2 Type 1", "VWModel 2 Type 2"]}}
```

Comment: This is close but not exactly what I need. I need each item with subelements appearing only once. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Harvey - thanks for edit, nested values are not dictionaries?

Comment: They are, your answer is on the spot. I've mistakenly put list on second level instead of dict, I'll corect that. Thank you!!